# How to change first char of each key in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with all keys in lover case and i need to change them that the firs char would be in uppercase, like `ucfirs` function does. Is it possible without creating a new array?

Comment: Not possible without creating a new array.

Comment: Can you explain why you need that? Why does it matter that the keys are ucfirst? Reason why I am asking is because I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible without creating a new array, but here's a funky one-liner you could use:

```
$array = array_combine(
    array_map('ucfirst', array_keys($array)), 
    array_values($array)
);
```

It breaks up the array into keys and values, transforms the keys and then glues the two pieces back together.

Comment: Simple and clean. Love it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        unset ($array[$key]);
        $array[ucfirst($key)] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Believe it or not, this actually creates another array :)

Comment: @Fluitketel Of course, it works. I'm just saying that a copy has been made internally the moment you `unset($array[$key])` for the first time.

Comment: @Jack That is possible. But this is not what he means by "without creating another array". The array name stays the same and that's what's important. Thanks for explaining though.

Comment: The variable name stays the same in my answer, too :)

Comment: @Jack Both our answers give the same output in the same amount of code. We both win!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    foreach ($arr as $key=>$val){
        unset($arr[$key]);
        $key = ucfirst($key);
        $arr[$key]=$val;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. it will work for nested array too.

```
<?php
function ucfirstKeys(&$data)
{
  foreach ($data as $key => $value)
  {
    // Convert key
    $newKey = ucfirst($key);

    // Change key if needed
    if ($newKey != $key)
    {
      unset($data[$key]);
      $data[$newKey] = $value;
    }

    // Handle nested arrays
    if (is_array($value))
    {
      ucfirstKeys($data[$key]);
    }
  }
}

$test = array('foo' => 'bar', 'moreFoo' => array('more' => 'foo'));
ucfirstKeys($test);
print_r($test);
```